# Icons in menu in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, menu

Is it possible to enable back icons in menus? I have already enabled switch in `org.gnome.desktop.interface.menus-have-icons` to `true` but it doesn't work. It works without problem in 16.04 but in 16.10 not.